# How to return a string (or JSON object) from a TypeScript function?

Tags: json, typescript

The following TypeScript function will retrieve data from a web API and display it to the console from within the function, but when I try to return the data object (a string) I get an error.  I am trying to return the JSON data object by `return data;` but the compiler thinks I am not returning anything.  Please, what am I doing wrong?

```
async function main(url: string, query: string): Promise<string> {

  const axios = require('axios');
  axios.get(url, {params: {"query": query}})
  .then(function (response: any) {
    let data = JSON.stringify(response.data);
    console.log("data: " + data);
    return data;
  })
  .catch(function (error: any) {
    console.log(error);
    return "error";
  });

}

var url: string = 'https://api.subquery.network/sq/AcalaNetwork/karura-tokens';
var query = "{accountBalances (first: 5) {nodes{id accountId tokenId total}}}"
var res = main(url, query).catch(e => console.error(e)).finally(() => process.exit(0))
console.log("res:" + res);
```

Here is the output:

```
src/index.ts:1:50 - error TS2355: A function whose declared type is neither 'void' nor 'any' must return a value.

1 async function main(url: string, query: string): Promise<string> {
```

In my example I am trying to return a string, but I am happy returning either a string or a JSON object. I just can't get either one to work.

Comment: Nothing is returned from `get_sq` and `res` is rightfully `undefined`

Comment: If you want to return something from the function, _return something from the function_. But it's going to be a _promise_ of the value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible solution (a bit hacky) is to return the promise from your function, declare your `res` variable in the global scope and, in the promise callback, assign the value the promise resolves to `res`.

But the actual assignment will only happen after the promise resolves, so you might set a timeout to use the variable outside the promise callback.

For example:

```
function get_sq(url: string, query: string): Promise<any>{
  const axios = require('axios');
  return axios.get(url, {params: {"query": query}});
}

var url: string = 'https://api.subquery.network/sq/AcalaNetwork/karura-tokens';
var query = "{accountBalances (first: 5) {nodes{id accountId tokenId total}}}"
var res;

get_sq(url, query).then(function (response: any) {
  res = JSON.stringify(response.data);
}).catch(function (error: any) {
  res = error;
});
  

setTimeout(() => {console.log("res:" + res);}, 3000);
```

Another possibility (the more robust one) is to keep inside the promise callback and do what you want to do with `res` there.